# Is There some way to load a bitmap on the Cimagelist using CBitmap::FromHandle?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to create a `Cimagelist` to insert on `ListCtrl`

List:

```
CImageList *cImageList;
cImageList = new CImageList();
cImageList->Create(120, 120, ILC_COLOR32, 0, 0);
```

if a load from `LoadBitmap` everthing works fine

```
CBitmap bitmap;
bitmap.LoadBitmap(IDB_ACCEPTABLE2);
cImageList->Replace(i, &bitmap, NULL);
bitmap.DeleteObject();
```

By if I try to use `CBitmap::FromHandle` my image is 100% black

```
CBitmap *bmp = CBitmap::FromHandle(OneFunction());
cImageList->Replace(i, bmp, NULL);
```

Is There some way to load a bitmap on the `Cimagelist` using `CBitmap::FromHandle` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented, [CBitmap::FromHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ydch1a3.aspx) creates a **temporary** object you do not own:

> If a CBitmap object is not already attached to the handle, a temporary CBitmap object is created and attached. This temporary CBitmap object is valid only until the next time the application has idle time in its event loop, at which time all temporary graphic objects are deleted. Another way of saying this is that the temporary object is only valid during the processing of one window message.

The object is owned by MFC, and garbage collected on the next idle processing loop. If you want to attach a [`CBitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t1yfd35.aspx) object to a `HBITMAP`, you need to manually call [`Attach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97h2k0zx.aspx):

```
CBitmap bmp;
bmp.Attach( OneFunction() );
```

or, if you need to manually control the object lifetime:

```
CBitmap* bmp{ new CBitmap() };
bmp->Attach( OneFunction() );
```

Comment: Thank you, I still have the problem because of the pointers, but your solution show some ways to resolve the problem.